# Setting up baseUrl and paths in VS Code's jsconfig.json to resolve .vue file

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code with Vue.js, I'm trying to setup VS Code to be able to display valid/invalid path of the files

Using following setting I can get correct valid/invalid sign (red underline below invalid path) but with .vue files, I only get invalid signs (both relative path and specified paths in `"compilerOptions"."paths"`

How to setup *jsconfig.json* or any other settings to make this working?  Please guide

Thanks

*Path*

```
|-jsconfig.json
+-src
|    +-components
|    |    |-Foo.js
|    |    |-Foo.vue
|    |    |-entry.js
```

*jsconfig.json*

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "checkJs": true,
        "module": "es2015",
        "target": "es6",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "Components": [ "./src/components" ]
        }
    }
}
```

*entry.js*

```
// no errors, Foo.js can be resolved
import F1 from 'Components/Foo'
// no errors, Foo.js can be resolved
import F2 from './Foo'
// errors, no Fo.js anyway
import F3 from 'Components/Fo'
// errors Foo.vue cannot be resolved
import F4 from 'Components/Foo.vue'
// errors Foo.vue cannot be resolved
import F5 from './Foo.vue'
```

> tsc version: 2.3.4